# Using getAssets() gives the error "The method getAssets() is undefined for the type ClassName"?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open a file which is in the assets folder. But using getAssets() gives the error given above. I know I have to pass the context from another activity, but I can't do that either as then another error comes-"The method onCreate(SQLiteDatabase, Context) of type ClassName must override or implement a supertype method". So I am stuck. Is there a better way of opening that file? Here is the line:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("file1.txt");
```

*Note: ClassName is not an activity, it's just a class, so getAssets() cannot work without passing context from another activity.

Edit: Here is the class and onCreate declaration:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {//some stuff
InputStream is = getAssets().open("file1.txt");
//more stuff
}
}
```

Comment: some java code would be nice man...

Comment: @Sajmon I added the line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am trying to open a file which is in the assets folder. But using getAssets() gives the error given above.

`getAssets()` is a method on `Context`.

> I know I have to pass the context from another activity, but I can't do that either as then another error comes-"The method onCreate(SQLiteDatabase, Context) of type ClassName must override or implement a supertype method".

Since you declined to paste the source code where this is occurring, it is difficult to help you.

> ClassName is not an activity, it's just a class

More specifically, it is a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

> so getAssets() cannot work without passing context from another activity.

A `SQLiteOpenHelper` gets passed a `Context` to its constructor, which you need to override.

Beyond all of this, if your objective is to package a database with your app, [please use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), as it has solved this problem.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("file1.txt");
```

Comment: Again an error comes saying "The method getActivity() is undefined for the type ClassName.".

Answer (score 4):

Use `getContext()` Method. Set `getContext().getAssets()`. I hope it will works .Actually **getAssets()** is a method on Context .
For more details you can visit [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#getContext)